# Changing Opacity Default in QGIS Layers Properties

Tags: qgis

Somehow the default for Opacity for Symbology has been set to 0% whenever I create a new vector layer in QGIS, and I have to change the setting to 100% to see the symbols.

How do I change the default back to 100% ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The setting to change the default for opacity is in Default Styles under Project/Properties.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer, this will help other people who experience this issue.